# javascript ajax autocomplete library

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I must make an autocomplete field on form. I use bootstrap and jquery.
And i want to know if there is a good library to do this ? Something complete and with a design near bootstrap if it's possible?

Thank in advance for sharing your experience

Comment: You want me to redirect you to Google?

Comment: What is Google ? :) I joke on google there is a lot of choice but not the most use library or i can find a library not use since several years.

Comment: You need to invest in your questions. Tell what have you tried and why you decided to come here at first place. Ex: "It is 2018 and these libraries are not maintained anymore..." With that, you show that you are not lazy and that you tried something. Also, you should get more familiar with rules on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i have choose this https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/ because i not want to use jquery-ui just for autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete . I use it . Awesome library.

Comment: I have used jqueryui in the past but i think it's no longer updated ?

Comment: the last version was on 2016

Comment: I've had trouble with this library when there are 10,000+ possibilities. It also can't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for autocomplete input field using local or remote data, you can try jQuery UI's autocomplete module. It provides singe or multiple choices.

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

If you only need multiple autocomplete selections, you can try `tag-it` but it does not provide in-built remote data fetch. It also depends on jQuery.

http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/

Here are few example of tags like input fields using vanilla js
https://bevacqua.github.io/insignia/
https://github.com/ORusak/tags-input

There is vanilla js version with no other dependencies provided by pixabay. But it allows selection of one item only.

https://goodies.pixabay.com/javascript/auto-complete/demo.html

There is a native HTML element `datalist` which might be a good fit for simple cases of local data. But be careful of browser compatibility.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: I have see that https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/ and https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ but typeaheadjs on github there is no mouvement since 3 years

Comment: I can't use html datalist because i need to get my data with ajax on remote server

Comment: i'm looking for a maintainer for my tag-it lib